# Keychain items nil upon successful login

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, authentication, keychain

I'm trying to upgrade my login system to include iOS Keychain. However, upon successful login, my keychain items are both nil. Currently, the code to save them is inside the same function called upon the click of the login button. Should I place them inside of the if statement itself? Should it have it's own function entirely?

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {

        KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"loginCredentials" accessGroup:nil];
        [keychainItem setObject:saveUsername forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
        [keychainItem setObject:savePassword forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];


        if([[self.usernameText text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.passwordText text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.usernameText text],[self.passwordText text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.techinworship.com/auth.php"];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];

                success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];

                }

                else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }

            } else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should save username and password into keychain after a registration ( or if you have only login, then after a successful login ).

Make a define for key in your class or in your app's pch. Something like this:

```
#define RES_USERNAME @"SAVE_USERNAME"
#define RES_PASSWORD @"SAVE_PASSWORD"
```

Save your data like this:

```
[KeychainItemWrapper save:RES_USERNAME data:email];
[KeychainItemWrapper save:RES_PASSWORD data:password];
```

Load your data if you want to automatic authentication:

```
NSString* email = [KeychainItemWrapper load:RES_USERNAME];
NSString* password = [KeychainItemWrapper load:RES_PASSWORD];
```

And of course delete if user want to delete himself from your app:

```
        [KeychainItemWrapper delete:RES_USERNAME];
        [KeychainItemWrapper delete:RES_PASSWORD];
```

EDIT:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)getKeychainQuery:(NSString *)service {
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (id)kSecClass,
            service, (id)kSecAttrService,
            service, (id)kSecAttrAccount,
            (id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, (id)kSecAttrAccessible,
            nil];
}

+ (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data {
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
    [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
}

+ (id)load:(NSString *)service {
    id ret = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(id)kSecMatchLimit];
    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;
    if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
        @try {
            ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)keyData];
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"Unarchive of %@ failed: %@", service, e);
        }
        @finally {}
    }
    if (keyData) CFRelease(keyData);
    return ret;
}

+ (void)delete:(NSString *)service {
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've defined them in both the pch prefix file, as well as, the .h and .m files of the class itself, but I'm still getting the error "No known class method for selector save:data". Also, I agree with only saving the credentials upon successful login, but where in the if statement would that fall?

Comment: I'm using this in my every app, so it's working fine

Comment: are you testing on your device?

Comment: yes, but due to the error I mentioned above, I can't even build, could you elaborate on the save:data selector and how I might set it up to work appropriately?